# How to convert WDSL to Java with Axistools-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I configured the axistools-maven-plugin as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <wsdlDirectory>/src/main/resources</wsdlDirectory>
        <wsdlFiles>
            <wsdlFile>adjustment.wsdl</wsdlFile>
        </wsdlFiles>
        <keep>true</keep>
        <allElements>true</allElements>
        <outputDirectory>/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
        <subPackageByFileName>true</subPackageByFileName>
        <useEmitter>true</useEmitter>
        <wsdlVersion>2</wsdlVersion>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

but my wsdl files are not being referred properly. Is the configuration correct?

I am getting the following info msg always

```
[INFO] Nothing to generate. All WSDL files are up to date.
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the `axistools-maven-plugin` issues an `[INFO] Skipping up to date wsdl: ...` for files not found instead of alerting about incorrect paths. Check your paths as suggested in the answers, and correct the `wsdlDirectory` to `sourceDirectory`, as per [MaDa](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7794917/413020) post.

Comment: For future reference, this plugin supports WSDLs RPC/encoded

Answer (score 8):

For me it was the directory parameter name. It's not `<wsdlDirectory>` but `<sourceDirectory>`. Anyway, here's my working config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <!--  A directory where the WSDL files reside: -->
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/</sourceDirectory>
        <!-- The list of WSDL files: -->
        <wsdlFiles>
            <wsdlFile>services.wsdl</wsdlFile>
        </wsdlFiles>
        <allElements>true</allElements>
        <!-- Where you want the generated files: -->
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
        <subPackageByFileName>true</subPackageByFileName>
        <useEmitter>false</useEmitter>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: did not generate java code.. created empty `generated-sources\annotations` folder, not even `generated-sources/wsdl2java`

Answer (score 6):

Got almost the same (info) message when i had a typo in wsdlFile!
The actual message was: "Skipping up to date wsdl"

e.g.

```
<sourceDirectory>src\main\resources\wsdl\release\x.y\</sourceDirectory>
<wsdlFiles>
       <wsdlFile>ABCWebservicex.y.wsdl</wsdlFile>  <!-- typo here -->
</wsdlFiles>
```

And the file present was: ABCWebservice_x.y.wsdl

Comment: In my case I had .WSDL correctly named but apparently it does not like caps.

Answer (score 2):

Skipping the leading slash in `/src/main/java` and `/src/main/resources` will probably help.

Edit: I've taken a closer look at my working configuration. I don't know how you came to this:

```
<wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources</wsdlDirectory>
```

Should probably be:

```
<sourceDirectory>src/main/resources</sourceDirectory>
```

Comment: After removing that leading slashes also getting the same info msg.

Comment: +1 I had to explicitly spell the `sourceDirectory` to  `${basedir}/src/main/wsdl` even though the plugin help (`mvn help:describe -Dplugin=org.codehaus.mojo:axistools-maven-plugin -Ddetail=true`) indicate that this is the default value!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using multiple wsdls under same wsdlfiles tag then you may encounter skipping info like below:

```
<wsdlFiles>
  <wsdlFile><file1>.wsdl</wsdlFile>
  <wsdlFile><file2>.wsdl</wsdlFile>                                 
</wsdlFiles>
```

In this case, either use single WSDL under wsdlfiles tag or use wsdloptions

```
<wsdlOptions>
  <wsdlOption>
    <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/<file>.wsdl</wsdl>                         
    <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl<file1>.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
  </wsdlOption>
</wsdlOptions>
```

Do `Maven Clean` > `Maven Update project` > `Maven Generated resources`. DONE !